# UK standard visitor visa refused: income in cash

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

Recently my mother applied for a UK standard visitor visa from India, which was refused. Her circumstances are:

- My mother owns land, which is cultivated, so we mentioned her as self-employed (agriculturist) with yearly income.
- We attached bank statements and certificate of fixed deposit from the bank.
- As all/most of the transactions in rural India are done in cash, there are no regular bank deposits.

**Reason for the refusal**:

- From refusal letter - "There is no indication that the funds in these accounts have been generated through your stated employment. This causes me to doubt your circumstances are as claimed and I am not satisfied that you have presented an accurate picture of your economic circumstances in India."

I am on a Tier 2 visa. I sponsored my mother's entire travel and stay in the UK, which they acknowledged. My wife and I are expecting a baby, so we wanted my mother to be here with us and stated this in the application as a reason for my mother's visit.

Edit (refusal letter)

[image]

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's difficult to provide documentation when everything is handled in cash, though I know that's common in many areas. Does she have receipts or other paperwork that could demonstrate the source of these funds?

Comment: Thank you, @zach, no she does not have the receipt, but we could try getting some documentation if that is acceptable, is there anything else we could do to strengthen new application?

Comment: Start depositing the cash payments into a bank account. Then you'll have a regular history of deposits to refer to in a future application. (But do *not* deposit a single large sum or they will suspect you of "funds parking".)

Comment: Thank you @roddy yes we will do a regular deposit for future applications, but is there any way to apply sooner? as we want my mother to visit us when the baby arrives.

Comment: How does your mother pay taxes? The government should give her some sort of receipt which would corroborate her cash income, and that should be accepted by UK immigration. If she doesn't pay taxes...

Comment: @Moo in South Asia agricultural taxes are usually negligible. I’m not saying she doesn’t pay them but I wouldn’t be surprised if that was so

Comment: @hankypanky From the wording of the question I imagined the applicant derived an income more as a landlord than a farmer. In any case, even small amounts of tax should attract a receipt

Comment: That's the irony. A landlord that owns farmland also enjoys massive tax benefits in all south Asian countries. Although this discussion is unrelated to the topic but having paid no direct taxes is quite a strong possibility in this case.

Comment: Thank you, guys. No, she does not pay taxes as agricultural income is exempted. After the first refusal, we decided to get that done so we are in discussion with CA to get the income tax return done, and planning to attach to next application. Still not sure if that is going to work or not.

Comment: The refusal notice says you provided certificates of balance but not account statements for one account. Providing detailed statements would go a long way towards satisfying the visa people.

Comment: Thank you, we did provide bank statement. Along with we provided a certificate of fix deposits, where they got confused. and stated missing bank statement.

Answer (score 2):

Income received in cash can and should be put into a bank account. The problem the visa authority probably has is not with the source of income (a doctor in India working independently, would also get most of his earning in cash) but the absence of inflows into a bank account.

Comment: Thank you, @Deans, based on circumstances what option do you think, I have to reapply?

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide sell bill of crops for proof of Income.  Also when you claim about your income you need provide documents for same and for same you can submit income certificate from local government like village panchayat.